# how to run Flutter app on IOS simulator in mac?

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

I want to run my flutter app on iOS simulator but I have this error:

```
Running pod install...                                             843ms
```

CocoaPods' output:
↳

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class.

 #  from /Users/admin/Downloads/myapp/ios/Podfile:43
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
 #  end
```

and when I `cd ios` and pod install it says :

**[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists' for File:Class.**

i also changed the

```
return [] unless File.exists file_path
```

but nothing works . any solution?

Comment: Try this:- 
In your vs code terminal -> cd ios -> pod install -> flutter run

Comment: thank you . this the result : [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Comment: cd ios -> pod init -> pod install -> flutter run

Comment: sorry for late answer . that didnt work as well , when I run pod init the return is : [!] Existing Podfile found in directory

Comment: try to delete that pod file then run:  pod init -> pod install